# Jekyll & Obsidian: images urls when using a baseurl

Tags: jekyll, obsidian

I'm new to jekyll and have been trying to set up a website, using Obsidian for managing the markdown posts.

Here's my setup:

- The website **has to** to be in a subfolder, so I need a baseurl (ex: /blog)
- I have all my images in a /media folder at root level of my website, like so http://example.com/blog/media/
- In my main pages (index.html as well as categories pages) I am making lists of posts that display an excerpt, each excerpt showing the header image that is inside the post (so it needs to be a root relative or absolute path, since the same image tag is displayed from a page at the root AND from a subfolder).
- As I said I am using Obsidian, so I would have preferred keeping the image links in the post in the following format: `![](media/image.jpg)`, otherwise the preview breaks and this is annoying for development.

I have tried multiple things, like so:

- with / at the beginning, like `![](/media/image.jpg)` > works everywhere when no baseurl, doesn't work with a baseurl (always goes to http://example.com/media/image.jpg instead of http://example.com/blog/media/image.jpg)
- without / at the beginning, like so `![](media/image.jpg)` > This is Obsidian's base way ot pointing to an image. It only works at the root level when baseurl is not empty, when from a subfolder it goes to http://example.com/sub/folders/media/image.jpg.
- with ./ at the beginning, like so `![](./media/image.jpg)` > when baseurl is not empty, works at root level, but not in post (goes to http://example.com/sub/folders/media/image.jpg) (note that this also breaks Obsidian image previews :( )

I've read a bit about relative_url, liquid filters and that kind of things, and from what I see with my tests the closest I get is to use a format with the / (`![](/media/image.jpg)`), and all I'd need is something that would always add /blog/ between http://example.com and /media.

It seems {{ site.baseurl }} does the trick, but that breaks Obsidian image preview and linking.

Is there a way to do so without having to add {{ site.baseurl }} in my img tag? I'd like to avoid it, but it seems it's the only thing that works...?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating a [hook](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/) to modify the rendered HTML image tags from Markdown during build. Essentially, trying to insert the string `/blog/` in the `src` attribute of your `<img src="media/image.jpg" />` tags.

Create a `.rb` file in a `_plugins` folder at the root of your project and copy this code. This code will iterate over each post and replace all occurrences of the first string with the second.

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_render do |post|
  post.output.gsub!('<img src="media/', '<img src="/blog/media/')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks 2-floor bro
I have successful apply this way to show my img in Obsidian and Web。
I also add others config in _config.yml:

> plugins:
> - jekyll-paginate
> - ./_plugins/build_hook.rb

because i still have one plugin value.
this is the one value config:

> plugins: [jekyll-paginate]

and just need to add a folder with the build_hook.rb file or other name.
Redepoly and u can see the good result !

here is my blog ([www.66dr.cn](http://www.66dr.cn)) but it's been dead for too long,I 'll update it in a short time